# Vertically Align multi-line text inside a span

Tags: html, css

I have spent countless hours yesterday and today to figure out how to do this. I cant believe CSS doesn't have an easy way to handle this.

Essentially, I have some text within a span class="name" whose length is not fixed. In certain instances, it can spill over to the next line. How do I vertically align this within my container.

More specifically, how do I vertically align "ABC Father And Sons Company LLC" within my container?
             http://jsfiddle.net/D3L8S/

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="name">ABC Father And Sons Company LLC  </span>
  <a href="#" class="addr">Address</a>
  <a href="#" class="hours">Hours</a> 
  <a href="#" class="more">More</a> 
</div>
```

css classes

```
// CSS
.container {
    background: #DDEBF0;
    padding: 11px;
    border: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
    width: 380px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height:18px;
    line-height:18px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.name {
    width:200px;
    float:left;
}

.addr, .hours, .more {
    width:60px;
    float:left;
}
```

If I add a negative top margin to "name" (margin-top:-8px), I can achieve this but it obviously messes up rendering for XYZ Company LLC 
            http://jsfiddle.net/FM4dA/

The solution should ideally be Cross-browser compatible (atleast ie8 should support it)

EDIT - I forgot to mention initially that my container width is fixed and cannot be changed.

Comment: Your div's padding is pushing the text down.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FM4dA/3/ ?

Comment: @j08691 - Thanks for your comment. But I need the padding for the container. Besides if I just remove the padding, it simply pushes the text outside the shaded boundary of the container. Please elaborate if I am misinterpreting what you are suggesting.

Comment: @İnekŞaban - Thanks. Actually my container size has to be fixed. Sorry, should've mentioned that in my original post.

Comment: Well my point is that your padding and height doesn't leave enough room to vertically center the multi-line content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it using inline blocks:

```
.container {
    background: #DDEBF0;
    padding: 11px;
    border: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
    width: 380px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
}

.name {
    width:200px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 1;
}

.addr, .hours, .more {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 1;
}
```

First, make sure to leave enough vertical space for multi-line names, so on `.container`,
I used `height: 50px` and `line-height: 50px`.

However, you need to reset the `line-height: 1` (or some suitable value) on the child elements otherwise the interline spacing will not be attractive.

Then, instead of floats, use `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle` on the
child elements (`.name`, `.addr`, `.hours`, `.more`).

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Wp84v/

Note: You may not need to specify the width on `.addr`, `.hours`, `.more`, so I let the
widths take on the shrink-to-fit value.

Comment: Thanks @Marc Audet. I like this solution more because it also vertically aligns the addr, hours and more fields within the container. Is there a way to tweak this to make the heights the same for both containers?

Comment: @user3573508 Please see update demonstrating a fixed height on the parent block.

Comment: Thanks @Marc Audet. Appreciate the help.

Comment: I tested this in both ie7 and ie8 (along with latest versions of Chrome and Firefox) and it works great. Thanks again @Marc Audet.

Answer (score 1):

One way to vertically align div's contents is to use the `vertical-align` css property. But it works only on `display:table-cell` elements. So, wrap your container into a `display:table` div, and change the container display to `display:table-cell`.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/D3L8S/2/

Comment: `table-cell` is a good way of doing this.  You do not need the wrapper with `display: table` (try it!) because the CSS engine will create an anonymous table element to wrap the table-cells as required.

Comment: Thanks @LcSalazar. This looks much better. A couple of questions 1) Is there a way to make both container heights the same? 2) Is this supported in ie8? How baout ie7?

Comment: Thanks @Marc Audet for pointing it out. Althouth on some browsers versions it is actually required to specify the wrapper div, on most of them you really don't.

Comment: The problem with the div's heigth, is the possibility of line breaking on the word, which increases the height. You could keep this from happening by adding the `white-space: nowrap` property to the div. Of course then you would increase the width size.

Comment: Thanks @LcSalazar. Unfortunately I cannot increase the width so the nowrap wouldnt work. I wish there was a way to force a uniform height for the containers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It might help somebody

```
.name {
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:-8px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/prime/FM4dA/13/)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to vertically center multiple lines, put the text into an inline block then pretend that the inline-block was a single line of text.

```
 .container {
    background: #DDEBF0;
    padding: 11px;
    border: 1px solid #D2D2D2;
    width: 380px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 18px;
    line-height: 18px
    display:inline-block;
 }

 .name {
     width:200px;
     float:left;
     margin-top:-8px;
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
     line-height: 14px;
 }
```

NOTE:

`Why you should add the line-height property ?`

If you add height to an element , where exactly does the text inside of it lie? That is, if you have a block of text that is font-size: 10px (a theoretical height:10px) inside a container that is 60px where exactly is the text going to end up? Most surely at the top of the container, because the text can only position itself where the text flows, inside a height:10px space. But you can overcome that by using a line-height value the same height as the container, this way the text will take in the vertical-align property and align itself properly.

Comment: Thanks MCHAppy - I guess your solution is along the lines of what @Marc Audet presented and should work too. I appreciate it!